# Configure Subversion in Xcode 5 with @ in user name (e-mail address)

Tags: svn, xcode5

I checked out a project from Subversion with [Versions](http://versionsapp.com). When I opened it in Xcode 5 it recognised the repository and marked files with an `M` in the navigator as I modified them. If I try to perform any subversion action Xcode complains that it cannot reach the server.

The repository's URL is correctly displayed as `user.name%40organization.org@project-url/svn` as we use out e-mail addresses as user name.

If I try to add the repo in Xcode's preferences under the "Accounts" tab I have two options:

- Entering the URL as above (I do this in Versions and it immediately recognises the user name as an e-mail address.). In this case Xcode adds `user.name` as user name and `project-url/svn` as URL. Clearly not what I wanted.
- Entering the URL without the user name and providing the e-mail address manually. This works (Xcode does not complain about not reaching the server.) but it won't recognise the project as belonging to the repo.

Is there a workaround? Is this a bug or is it me?

Comment: I submitted the problem with recognising `user.name%40organization.org` as user name `user.name` in Apple's bug tracker as number 15361456.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has closed my bug report as duplicate of the still open bug 9303236.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem we faced during Bot integration because in my user name "@" is present. The other alternate solution is that create the SSH key for authentication. we did on git based repo and able successfully created Bot for my project